# Gallery with Splide JS : How to force the line of thumbnails not to exceed the size of my container

Tags: javascript, wordpress, splidejs

i try to use splide JS (this is a JS library to create Carousel, Gallery, Slider... like Swiper JS) in order to create a slider.

I created this slider : https://splidejs.com/tutorials/gallery/ by following the tutorial. It works, but the problem is that i've got a lot of image to put in the slider, so the thumbnail row is very long and it's expands my container. If i've got 50 images, my page will be extra large. You can see the result on my website : [image: My slider is to large because of the thumbnail row]

This is the code i written by following Splide JS doc :

```
var splide = new Splide( '#main-carousel', {
    pagination: true,
    type   : 'loop',
    perPage: 1,
    width: "500px",
    } );


var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName( 'thumbnail' );
var current;


for ( var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++ ) {
  initThumbnail( thumbnails[ i ], i );
}


function initThumbnail( thumbnail, index ) {
  thumbnail.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    splide.go( index );
  } );
}


splide.on( 'mounted move', function () {
  var thumbnail = thumbnails[ splide.index ];


  if ( thumbnail ) {
    if ( current ) {
      current.classList.remove( 'is-active' );
    }


    thumbnail.classList.add( 'is-active' );
    current = thumbnail;
  }
} );


splide.mount();
```

We can se that the width of my main image (before the thumbnail) has 500px. I set that because if i don't specify, the image will take 100% of the wide created by the thumbnail row.

My goal is to achieve this result :
The main image in the thumbnail row has the same width that the container. For the thumbnail row, we can drag left to right in order to see the thumbnail which are after the container limit.

The options available are here : https://splidejs.com/guides/options/
I have tried many thing but i can't achieve it.

You can see the live website here : https://agencegrance.com/prestataire/admin/

thanks a lot